# How to use QtWebEngine in QML

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I want to use QtWebEngine in QML with PyQT. I am trying to run simple example.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

if __name__ == '__main__':

   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   view = QQmlApplicationEngine('main_2.qml')
   #view.show()
   app.exec_()
   sys.exit()
```

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtWebEngine 1.0

Window {
    width: 1024
    height: 750
    visible: true
    WebEngineView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: "https://www.qt.io"
    }
}
```

But I've get error:

> /usr/bin/python3 /home/unknown/IdeaProjects/new_ui/main.py
>   QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
>   file:///home/unknown/IdeaProjects/new_ui/main_2.qml:3 module 
>   "QtWebEngine" is not installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PyQt 5.12 QtWebEngineWidgets has been separated into another package called [PyQtWebEngine](https://pypi.org/project/PyQtWebEngine/), so you have to install it with:

```
python -m pip install PyQtWebEngine
```